# How to do this JOIN query in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

I'm trying to do this join in laravel query builder but it is throwing and error. I'm using and Mysql DB.
This is my sql:

```
select c.*, d.* from notas_cabecera c
join notas_detalle d on (c.codigo_nota = d.codigo_nota)
where c.codigo_nota in (select r.codigo_nota from reportes r);
```

And this is my laravel query:

```
$lista_reportes = DB::table('notas_cabecera')
                              ->join('notas_detalle', 'notas_cabecera.codigo_nota', '=', 'notas_detalle.codigo_nota')
                              ->whereIn('notas_cabecera.codigo_nota', function($query)
                              {
                                    $query->select(
                                              DB::table('reportes')->select('reportes.codigo_nota')
                                            );
                              })
                              ->get();
```

What I'm doing wrong? please help.

Comment: For starters, you're not telling us what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lista_reportes = DB::table('notas_cabecera')
                              ->join('notas_detalle', 'notas_cabecera.codigo_nota', '=', 'notas_detalle.codigo_nota')
                              ->whereIn('notas_cabecera.codigo_nota', function($query)
                              {
                                    $query
                                        ->select('reportes.codigo_nota')
                                        ->from('reportes');
                              })
                              ->get();
```